# Регистрация с помощью Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, php

Есть два PHP файла - registration.php (выводит форму для регистрации) и registration_new.php (обрабатывает данные полученные от файла registration.php методом POST и записывает их в базу данных). Вопрос - Как можно осуществить передачу данных, введенных в форму на странице registration.php, странице registration_new.php с помощью AJAX (jQuery)?

### registraton.php

```
<?php
    header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
    header('Content-type: text/html');

    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $title = "Регистрация";

    require_once('header.php');

    //инициализирум механизм сесссий
    session_start(); 
    #echo (session_id()); #отладка
    #echo("<br>");
?>  
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function (){
            $("#create_account").submit(function(e){
                var email = $("#email").val();
                alert(!!email.match(/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,4})+$/));
                //e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
    </script>
    <section id="middle" class="group">
        <div id="container">
            <div id="content">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <form id="create_account" action="registration_new.php" method="POST">
                        <fieldset id="singup">
                            <legend>Создайте новый аккаунт</legend>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <label for="username"><i class="icon-user"></i>Логин:</label>
                                    <input id="username" type="text" autofocus name="username" placeholder="John" tabindex="1">
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <label for="email"><i class="icon-envelope"></i>Email:</label>
                                    <input id="email" type="text" name="email" placeholder="user@example.com" autocomplete="off" tabindex="2">
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <label for="password"><i class="icon-question-sign"></i>Пароль:</label>
                                    <input id="password" type="password" name="password" value="" autocomplete="off" placeholder="8-10 символов" tabindex="3">
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <label for="password_confirm"><i class="icon-question-sign"></i>Повторите пароль:</label>
                                    <input id="password_confirm" type="password" name="password_confirm" value="" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Введите пароль еще раз" tabindex="4">
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary" tabindex="5"><span><i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i></span>Зарегистрироваться</button>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div><!-- #content-->
        </div><!-- #container-->
        <aside id="sideRight">
            <p>Зарегистрируйтесь, чтобы стать полноценным участником сервиса. Вы сможете голосовать, участвовать в рейтинге и использовать личные сообщения для общения с другими пользователями.</p>
        </aside><!-- #sideRight -->
    </section><!-- #middle-->
<?php
    require_once('footer.php');
?>
```

### registarion_new.php

```
<?php
    header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
    header('Content-type: text/html');

    $title = "Регистрация прошла успешно!";

    require_once("header.php");

    //Подключение к БД
    require_once("mysql.php");

    #echo (session_id()); #отладка
    #echo("<br>");

    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    //Создать короткие имена переменных
    $username = trim(strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['username']))); #login
    $email = trim(strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']))); 
    $password = trim(strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['password'])));
    $password_confirm = trim(strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['password_confirm'])));
    $date = date("d-m-Y H:i:s"); //Дата регистрации пользователя, чтобы можно было посчитать сколько дней и часов участник на сайте. Например - На сайте: 22 дня 13 часов.

    echo $date;

    //Проверка e-mail с помощью php (на стороне сервера)
    function validateEmail($email)
    {
        $pattern = "/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,4})+$/";
        if(!preg_match($pattern, $email)) 
        {
            return die("<br>Введите корректный email адрес.<br>");
        }
    }

    echo validateEmail($email);

    if($password === $password_confirm)
    {
        $query = "INSERT INTO users (id, username, email, password, `date`)
                VALUES(0, '$username', '$email', SHA1('$password'), NOW())";
        $result = mysql_unbuffered_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

        mysql_free_result($result);
        mysql_close($conn);

        echo("<div class=\"alert alert-success\">");
        echo("<h1>Регистрация прошла успешно!</h1><hr>\n");
        echo("<h2>Письмо с регистрационными данными было отправлено\n Вам на email - $email</h2>\n");
        echo("<p>Проверьте свою электронную почту, чтобы завершить регистрацию.</p>\n");
        echo("<p>Если письмо не придет на Ваш почтовый ящик в течении 15 минут после регистрации, проверьте, пожалуйста, папку \"Спам\".</p>\n");
        echo("<p>Если письмо от нашего сервиса попало в папку \"Спам\", отметьте его как не спам и, пожалуйста, добавьте на электронный адрес <span>add@askdev.ru</span> в Вашу адресную книгу.\n");
        echo("</div>");
    }
    else
    {
        echo("<div class=\"alert alert-error\">");
        echo("<p>Введите пароль еще раз!</p>\n");
        echo("</div>");
    }

    require_once("footer.php");
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Почитать про [ajax()](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/Ajax-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81) облом? )) Напишу очень кратко и схематически, а дальше уже сами.

**HTML**

```
<form id="reg_form">
    <input type="text" id="log" name="login" value="" />
    <input type="password" id="pass" name="pass" value="" />
    <input type="button" id="go" value="Регимся" />
<form>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#go').click(function(){
    // или сериализируем данные формы
    // var regData = $('#reg_form').serialize();

    // или обрабатываем поля по отдельности
    var userLog = $.trim($('#log').val());
    var userPas = $.trim($('#pass').val());

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'handler.php',
        data: {user_login : userLog, user_pass: userPas},
        error: function(req, text, error) {
            alert('Ошибка AJAX: ' + text + ' | ' + error);
        },
        success: function (data) {
            // в data[0] - содержит значение $success
            // в data[1] - содержит значение $login (или имя юзверя)
            if(data[0]){
                alert(data[1] + ', вы зарегистрированы!');
            } else {
                alert('Хьюстон, у нас проблемы!');
            }
        },
        dataType: 'json'
    });
});
```

**handler.php (обработчик)**

```
if(isset($_POST['user_login'], $_POST['user_pass'])){
    $success = false;
    $login = $_POST['user_login'];
    $pass = $_POST['user_pass'];
    // дальше все ваши проверки, валидации и прочее
    // если всё гуд, то $success = true;
    // и возвращаем результат обработки:
    echo json_encode(array($success, $login));
    exit();    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Можете отправлять ajax форму с помощью jQuery плагина **jQuery Form Plugin**. 
Будет даже проще чем jQuery().ajax
Отправить данные могут две функции:

```
jQuery('#myForm1').ajaxForm(options)
```

или

```
jQuery('#myForm1').ajaxSubmit(options);
```

[Здесь примеры](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#ajaxForm)